# Android Kotlin Testing for Intent putExtra Value

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

`android studio 4.1.1` and Kotlin.  I'm a beginner learning via tutorials.

I have an activity in which I am using an Intent to go to another activity.  I'm using `intent.putExtra`:

```
val intent = Intent(this, WeightExercise::class.java)
intent.putExtra("POSITION", positionToString)
startActivity(intent)
```

In the WeightExercise activity I get the value passed with:

```
// with line numbers:

80: var myPosition = intent.getStringExtra("POSITION").toString()
81: var position = myPosition.toInt()
```

This works.  I get the string value in `POSITION`.

Problem: I have another activity that uses an Intent to go to the WeightExercise activity.  It is NOT passing in a value via the intent.  When this happens, line 81 (above) in WeightExercise activity causes an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
at com.johndcowan.liftit.WeightExercise.onCreate(WeightExercise.kt:81)
```

I've tried a few `if()`s to test for a null or empty value, but nothing gets me past this error.

```
if ( intent.getStringExtra("POSITION").toString().isNullOrEmpty() ) {...}
if ( myPosition.isNullOrEmpty() ) {...}
if ( myPosition == null ) {...}
```

Is there a better way to test for a named string `POSITION` in an intent?

thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `getStringExtra()` is nullable, but you are converting it to a non-null String with a possible value of `"null"` by using `toString()` on the result. So Kotlin doesn't enforce the nullability when you try to convert it to an Int. You should omit `toString()` and use a null-safe call (`?.`) when working with the return value.

```
val myPosition = intent.getStringExtra("POSITION")
val position = myPosition?.toIntOrNull()
if (position != null) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Kotlin [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#null-safety)

Set a default value when extra is null if needed.

```
var myPosition = intent?.extras?.getStringExtra("POSITION") ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Find more about [`?:` Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)